# INNER JOIN'ed columns from tables are not displayed - without any errors

Tags: postgresql, inner-join, where-clause

I have three tables 1 and 2 are basic and 3rd have relation to 1 and 2. I'm trying to display display only some records from table 3 using WHERE, however I want the values from basic tables also be displayed along with query results.

I was trying to use inner join (before WHERE), but there is only result of SELECT x, y FROM t3 WHERE condition; -> This result is properly displayed However my to INNER JOIN lines seems as they are ignored - there is no error, the joined

```
SELECT komputery.nazwa, komputery.id FROM komputery
INNER JOIN system_op ON komputery.system_op = system_op.id
INNER JOIN sl_org ON komputery.lokalizacja = sl_org.id
WHERE system_op IN (SELECT id FROM system_op WHERE nazwa='Windows 7' AND architektura='x64') 
OR lokalizacja IN (SELECT id FROM sl_org WHERE nazwa='IT');
```

There is no errors.
**Actual:**
Only SELECT x, y FROM t3 WHERE condition is displayed
**Expected:**
Display values from tables that I have relation to in T3 for e.g. If I'm selecting only windows 7 x64 PC from T3 - I also want to have displayed Windows 7 x64 (which is in basic table) next to the results from T3 (which is using relation to get Windows 7 x64)

Comment: The `WHERE` filter will apply to the rows from `komputery` that are being joined on, BEFORE the join on the other tables takes place. If there are no matching rows from that table, there will be no rows to be joined on.

Answer (score 0):

OK I found what was the issue. After SELECT i didn't select any columns from table I was joining in. So no values were displayed:

```
SELECT komputery.nazwa, komputery.id, system_op.nazwa as system_operacyjny, system_op.architektura, sl_org.nazwa as lokalizacja FROM komputery
INNER JOIN system_op 
ON komputery.system_op = system_op.id
INNER JOIN sl_org 
ON komputery.lokalizacja = sl_org.id
WHERE system_op IN (SELECT id FROM system_op WHERE nazwa='Windows 7' AND architektura='x64') 
OR lokalizacja IN (SELECT id FROM sl_org WHERE nazwa='IT');
```

This code works properly.